# Azure Log's Management

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, system.diagnostics

I'm developing an application hosted on Windows Azure. I want to set up a log's management to allow me to debug the application easier. Do you think Windows Azure logs management system may be enough or should I add a tool as log4net ? Thanks

Comment: are you using web apps?

Comment: what does about mean ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion log4net or nlog will be much better because you redirect some messages to azure log managment, some to files, etc.
You will have bigger control then simple write to log managment

Comment: I have considered what you say, and so I've turned to Nlog . I managed to make good progress but my last point is : how can I do that log file is created in blob in azure, please ?

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. Could you precise?

Comment: Sorry, how can I do to redirect Nlog messages to azure log management, please ?
The person superior to me told me that I must to create a log file and then put it in Azure with blob, but without additional help. Thanks

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial https://maximelabelle.wordpress.com/2015/01/16/integrating-nlog-with-azure-cloud-service-diagnostics/

Comment: Sorry for the delay , I was in school week. The instructions of the previous link are given for Azure SDK <2.5 right? Now I am in version 2.5  I understand it doesn't work the same method ?

Comment: Thanks Garath, I will try it. But just a question of configuration : what is the best method to do when you have multiple cloud services? I have 3 and I don't know how to do this. I set the local storage of 3 and for log I make a worker role ? A Worker Role can it called in multiple cloud services ? Thanks.

Comment: So, I created a Log's worker role for one cloud service for the moment. I configured as the tutorial, but my folder named "DiagnosticsStore" isn't created. do I completely redeploy the application on Azure ? Or simply doing to clean, rebuild and play the project in visual studio is sufficient ? Thanks.

Comment: rebuild should be enough

Comment: Yes, he creates a local repository but does not transfer log files to azure for the moment